# pg_dump is not the same version as psql

Tags: postgresql

I updated postgres to version 14 by simply running `sudo apt upgrade`.

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1)
```

But `pg_dump` did not upgrade with everything else:

```
pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-2.pgdg20.04+1)
```

Any idea why that is? If I completely uninstalled postgres to do a fresh install would I lose any local databases as well?

Update:
I purged everything postgres and reinstalled `postgresql-14`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-14
```

```
pg_dump --version      
Error: PostgreSQL version 12 is not installed
```

Currently on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What OS+version are you running? How did you update PostgreSQL? Were there any warnings during the upgrade? Where is the package from?

Comment: Added both, sorry for the missing info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-14`. pg_dump utility comes from there, not from `postgresql`.